# Spring: Form is not getting redirected to given method in action url while submitting it

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm starting to learn spring framework and in my code I'm simply trying to create an empty form and checking whether it is getting redirected to proper controller method. When i specify a javascript function in form submission action the function is getting executed but when I specify an URL which can be mapped to a controller method, the controller method is not getting called instead it is going to mainPage of the application. I'm not getting any errors in the log. Please guide on this.

**My view (.ftl):**

```
<div class="form-page-header">
  <h4 class="page-heading">First exercise</h4>
</div>
<form id="EmptyForm" class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="<@spring.url  "/user/create"/>">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <b>User Details</b>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">

      <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-5 control-label">Create New User</label>

        <div class="col-sm-7">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group pull-left">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Submit" />
  </div>

</form>
```

My Controller:

**UserController.java**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/user")
public class ServerController implements MessageSourceAware {

    private MessageSource messages;
    private UserService userService;


    @Override
    public void setMessageSource(MessageSource messageSource) {
        this.messages = messageSource;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setUserService(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String list(ModelMap modelMap) {
        System.out.println("inside user controller");
        return "user/view";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView create(ModelMap modelMap) {
        System.out.println("create server mapped...");
        modelMap.addAttribute("server", new User());
        ModelAndView mnv = new ModelAndView();
        mnv.setViewName("user/view");
        return mnv;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you see any redirect in the browser dev tool?

Comment: Actually i have a request mapping for "/" that reutrns home page view. So m request is getting mapped to this instead of "/create" @RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/welcome**"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home() {


     return "home/home";
        }
    }

Comment: Have you tried `action="/user/create"` only? See if that works. It's a little awkward with all those double quotations.

Comment: Yes i tried it but didn't work that way too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now the issue is resolved. We have some security checks in the application, so I had to include the CSRF token in my .ftl file and it resolved the issue.